# Problem routing packets between two routers (EdgeMarc 4550)

Tags: routing

I'm having problems at my company's colocation routing between two routers.

We have two IP blocks: a "standard" .56/29 and a routed .128/28.

We were having issues with our PBX, so we resurrected an EdgeMarc 4550 (apparently good with VoIP) and put the PBX behind that and left the rest of our equipment behind our Netgear ProSafe FVS318G. The Netgear is at .57 and the Edgemarc is at .58. It looks something like this:

```
                 "The Internet"
                       |
1.1.1.57 ------ HP ProCurve 1700 ------- 1.1.1.58
(NetGear)    (used as simple switch)    (EdgeMarc)
```

I can NAT all kinds of IPs from the /28 block into machines on the Netgear LAN, but when I try to do the same thing on the EdgeMarc, the IPs get routed to .57 (as seen from tracert). I believe that I must be doing something wrong on the EdgeMarc as it is more powerful than what I'm used to dealing with; here's the the configuration I have set up on the EdgeMarc (EM):

- NAT -> Port Forwarding: set up for my .136 address into the EM LAN
- Static Route: 1.1.1.136, 255.255.255.255, 1.1.1.58
- Security -> Pass-through rules: DMZ set up for internal addresses

One more thing of note, I can set up the same static route on the NetGear and computers on the NetGear LAN can reach 1.1.1.136 without a problem, it's just traffic coming in from "The Internet" don't get routed properly.

Any thoughts? I am a one-man show when it comes to IT, but I can usually figure things out with a good bit of research and trial/error, but this one has me stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer through further discussion with my Colocation center. Apparently all traffic was routed to the Netgear router (.57), including the IPs in the /28 block.